# Unity&MacOSでクリップボードに画像をコピーするネイティブプラグインを作成したい

Tags: swift, unity3d, swiftui

Unity&MacOSでクリップボードに画像をコピーするネイティブプラグインを作成しようとしているのですが、Swiftの書き方がさっぱりで助けてください。

XCodeでbundleのプロジェクトを作成し、

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

@_cdecl("SetImagePasteboard")
public func SetImagePasteboard(_ stringPtr: UnsafePointer<CChar>?)
{
    let str = String(cString: stringPtr!)
    let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: str)

    NSPasteboard.general.clearContents()
    NSPasteboard.general.writeObjects([image])
}
```

このようなコードを書いたところ、writeObjectsの行で

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

とエラーになってしまいます。
ここはどう書くべきなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。これでいけました。

```
@_cdecl("SetImagePasteboard")
public func SetImagePasteboard(_ stringPtr: UnsafePointer<CChar>?) {
    let str = String(cString: stringPtr!)
    let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: str)

    let tiffdata = image?.tiffRepresentation

    NSPasteboard.general.clearContents()
    NSPasteboard.general.setData(tiffdata, forType: .tiff)
}
```